# How to exclude a set of events from being processed by QT's event loop?

Tags: qt, user-interface, events, event-handling, qt5

I need to be able to exclude a set of events from being processed by the event loop; I am aware there are flags that can be passed onto processEvents method (e.g. QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents, which processes only events that are not user inputs, but leaves the user input events there for later processing), but is there a way to process only a specific subset (or, equivalently, exclude a specific subset) of events? I've been able to accomplish something similar using an event filter, but the events are discarded instead of simply not processing, which is not what I want. I was not able to find a way to do that, hence this question; would one have to rewrite QT's internals to do that or is there some functionality for that purpose? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give an explanation of why you want to do that? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: There is a progress bar widget whose work load associated is not processed on a separate thread, but rather on the main one (the code base is quite huge so refactoring isn't a viable option); processEvents is called with the sole purpose of updating the window on screen and to prevent the application from hanging (not respond). I want to only process the events needed for that to happen (the widget to be updated on the screen) because the processEvents call is reentrant and causes bugs

Comment: I should perhaps specify that by "a set of events" I mean a set of type of events, although that is inferrable by mentioning QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents

Comment: If you want to do this in the main application event loop, then you can override `QCoreApplication::notify()` and there you just create a static local variable `QSet<int>` (for example) where you will insert all the event types and then just check whether the concrete event has type present or not present in the set. And if the evnt is not supposed to be processed, then just ignore it and return.

Comment: Even if it is possible, just delaying events is also a kind of 'hanging'. What kind of events are you trying to delay?

Comment: All of them except the ones needed to visually update the widget in which the QProgressBar is, to prevent the "application is not responding" message from the OS and simultaneously show the progress bar on screen; repaint method does not work for some reason, and update wouldn't suffice since the proper event loop would only be executed after the processing from the progress bar; a bug occurs more specifically because a QEvent::MetaCall is processed and triggers an unwanted flow of execution

Comment: So, isn't the root issue that you are emitting that `QEvent::MetaCall`? Or capture it (f.ex. using event filter as you achieved already) and queue it yourself.

Comment: Are these events the result of a signal/slot connection? If so, could you use QSignalBlocker to block the signals in the first place? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignalblocker.html#details

Comment: How would one go about queuing the events discarded by the event filter, @m7913d? I tried saving them into a vector and posting them with postEvent but the application crashed; the root cause may be that, I am uncertain of what triggers that event in the first place

Comment: @linuxfever, blocking an event is not desirable (by discarding the metacall event, for instance, another bug appears)

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager, ignoring all of the details of the specific problem I'm dealing with, your comment seems to be a way to generically do what my question covers; write it as an answer and I'll accept it as a valid one

Comment: @DaviFN I added an answer with some example code.

Comment: Overall this question is such a strange requirement that I tend to think this is an X-Y problem... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem You should probably explain why do you need this strange thing because this may help to clarify it or propose some alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

At global level you can try to override `QCoreApplication::notify()` event handler. There you can create a set of event types which you ignore.

In the following example I override `QApplication` and ignore all mouse click related events. When clicking on the widget, there should be NO messages displayed. If you comment-out the `notify()` override, debug messages will be displayed.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) override
    {
        qDebug() << "mouse button pressed";
    }
};

class Application : public QApplication
{
public:
    Application(int argc, char *argv[]) : QApplication(argc, argv)
    {
    }

    bool notify(QObject *object, QEvent *event) override
    {
        // e.g. sink for all mouse click events
        static QSet<int> ignoredEvents = { QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick };
        if (ignoredEvents.contains(event->type()))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return QApplication::notify(object, event);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: How would this functionally differ from the event filter, though, in the sense that both ignore and discard the events? I seek a way to temporarily disable processing of the set of events amidst a processEvents call, but keeping the events somewhere for later processing (later would be the time the main event loop executes or another call to processEvents happens); discarding the events causes bugs in my case and considering them outside of the event loop also causes bugs in my case

Comment: Yes, this is just an alternative to event filter installed on `QApplication` object. Just another of achieving the same effect. If this is not what you want then I probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: It is very close to what I want, but instead of discarding the events I need to postpone their processing... both returning true from an event filter and returning true from notify would ignore the processing of the event but would discard then in the sense they'd be lost and never processed; I seek a way to only process a subset of events when calling processEvents, without discarding the others

Comment: This is such a strange requirement... what is the reason for this? Is this some strange mechanism to keep UI responsive without using threads? Btw. there is a way to override `QAbstractEventDispatcher` https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstracteventdispatcher.html but it is probably quite difficult to do it right. I have never done it yet.

Comment: Yes, it is a strange mechanism to keep the UI responsive without using threads. More specifically, to visually update (i.e. paint) a widget to keep the progress bar and associated elements (text) being updated to the user. According to QT's documentation, the repaint method should be able to do it but it does not work; the only thing that works so far is directly sending a WM_PAINT message to the underlying Windows native window

Comment: @DaviFN Instead of discarding them, could you instead post them back to the queue, like so: `postEvent(object, new QEvent(*event));`?

Comment: I tried that; saved them into a vector right before discarding them in the event loop, and after the processEvents call posted each one of them, but the application crashes; I assumed it was wrong to do it that way

Comment: @DaviFN you have to create copies of the events on the heap, using new. Otherwise you'll get a crash. Did you do it that way?

Comment: I did; also tried now without saving them onto a vector, directly posting within the event filter right before discarding them returning true, but also crashed. Wasn't it supposed to crash? If it was not, there might be some more wrong stuff in the architecture that makes it crash

Comment: @DaviFN I don't believe it should crash. How are you ensuring that these events do not keep getting pushed back to the queue repeatedly? Are you removing the eventFilter at some point or something like that?

Comment: The event filter is set right before the call to processEvents and removed right after processEvents has returned; is there a way to derive from the concrete class of QAbstractEventDispatcher? With the purpose of reimplementing processEvents

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a late response, but I recently encountered the same issue. For those who are facing a similar problem and prefer a consolidated solution rather than reading through numerous comments, I’ve put together an answer with a code example.

**In brief**, the solution involves handling all events. If you wish to postpone an event, you simply need to store it for later use.

**Example**, let’s modify the code from @hifile-app-best-file-manager’s answer. We’ll store the events we’re planning to discard and then reapply them later. Here’s how we should extend the Application class:

```cpp
class Application : public QApplication
{
public:
    Application(int argc, char *argv[]);
    void activetePostponing(bool active); // to determine should we pospotone events
    bool notify(QObject *object, QEvent *event) override;

private:
    bool _postponingActive{false};
    std::vector<std::pair<QObject *, QEvent *>> _buffer; // for buffered events
};
```

We’ll add a new function that attempts to apply the stored events:

```
void Application::activetePostponing(bool active)
{
    _postponingActive = active;
    if(active)
        return;
    for(auto& [obj, event]: _buffer)
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(obj, event);
    _buffer.clear();
}
```

We’ll also modify the existing `notify` function to store events instead of discarding them:

```
bool Application::notify(QObject *object, QEvent *event) override
{
    // e.g. sink for all mouse click events
    static QSet<int> ignoredEvents = { QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick };
    if (_postponingActive && ignoredEvents.contains(event->type()))
    {
        _buffer.emplace_back(object, event->clone());
        return true;
    }
    return QApplication::notify(object, event);
}
```

With these changes, the main function now allows for the postponing state to be altered. Here’s the complete code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) override
    {
        qDebug() << "mouse button pressed";
    }
};

class Application : public QApplication
{
public:
    Application(int argc, char *argv[]) : QApplication(argc, argv)
    {
    }

    bool notify(QObject *object, QEvent *event) override
    {
        // e.g. sink for all mouse click events
        static QSet<int> ignoredEvents = { QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick };
        if (_postponingActive && ignoredEvents.contains(event->type()))
        {
            _buffer.emplace_back(object, event->clone());
            return true;
        }

        return QApplication::notify(object, event);
    }
    void activetePostponing(bool active)
    {
        _postponingActive = active;
        if(active)
            return;
        for(auto& [obj, event]: _buffer)
            QCoreApplication::postEvent(obj, event);
        _buffer.clear();
    }

private:
    bool _postponingActive{false};
    std::vector<std::pair<QObject *, QEvent *>> _buffer; // for buffered events
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    QObject::connect(&w, /*some event here*/, &a, &Application::activetePostponing); // here we just state for postponing
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```